# R lapply on list of dataframes resetting rownames

Tags: r, dataframe

You can reset the rownames in a data frame by running

```
>rownames(df) <- NULL
```

I have a list of dataframes and want to reset all the rownames on every dataframe in the list, I tried

```
>newlist <- llply(mylist, function(df) { rownames(df) <- NULL })
```

Bu tit doesn't work, returns a list of NULLS and the original remains unchanged.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a job for the base function `lapply`; you don't need to load plyr. You also need to make sure that your anonymous function returns something.

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=1:10)
rownames(df1) <- letters[1:10]

df2 <- data.frame(b=1:10)
rownames(df2) <- LETTERS[1:10]

mylist <- list(df1,df2)

mylist <- lapply(mylist,function(DF) {rownames(DF) <- NULL; DF})
```

Comment: +1 If you wanted to be a little more concise you could write `lapply( mylist , \`rownames<-\` , NULL )`

Answer (score 5):

Use `rownames<-` :

```
newlist <- lapply(mylist, "rownames<-", NULL)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem any different (other than cosmetic) to Roland's answer or my subsequent comment under his answer.

Comment: Hadn't noticed your comment.  This one does use double quotes :)