# `rowname`-ing a list of matrices

Tags: r, r-rownames

Suppose I have a list of matrices called `Tables` with colnames and without rownames.

```
 Tables <- list(structure(c(0.810145949194718, 0.0792559803788517, 0.189854050805282, 
0.920744019621148), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("e", "prod"))), structure(c(0.949326264941026, 0.24010922539329, 
0.0506737350589744, 0.75989077460671), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("prod", "e"))))
```

I want the rownames to be the same as the colnames:

```
rownames(Tables[[1]])<- colnames(Tables[[1]])
rownames(Tables[[2]])<- colnames(Tables[[2]])
```

I've tried using `lapply` with no success

```
lapply(Tables, function(x) rownames(x) <- colnames(x))
```

I managed to do it using a `for` loop

```
for(i in 1:length(Tables)){
  rownames(Tables[[i]])<- colnames(Tables[[i]])
}

Tables # Expected result
[[1]]
              e      prod
e    0.81014595 0.1898541
prod 0.07925598 0.9207440

[[2]]
          prod          e
prod 0.9493263 0.05067374
e    0.2401092 0.75989077
```

Nevertheless, I want to find a way to do it using any `*apply` or any other function in base to avoid the `for` loop, but I can't succeed on this target.  I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938064/r-lapply-on-list-of-dataframes-resetting-rownames) but I can't figure out how to use any of those solutions. Any suggestion?

Comment: FYI, the matrices in the `Tables` object you've supplied already have matching column and row names.

Comment: This is a simple enuff operation that I don't see anything wrong, or slow, w/ using a `for` loop

Comment: I don't know why @Henrik deleted his answer, but I agree with him: your anonymous function in `lapply` needs to return `x`, i.e., `lapply(Tables, function(x) {rownames(x) <- colnames(x); x})`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien thanks, I edited to supply the right (no rownames) list

Comment: Ohh Roland you're absolutely right. :D

Comment: @Roland, I started to doubt my answer when I realized the original Table had rownames. Had to create a new matrix to check that it worked. And I think it did...

Comment: @Henrik unblock your answer and will mark it as correct, It works perfectly, you didnt gave the opportunity to accept it. My fault posting the wrong example

Comment: @Jilber, I undeleted a while ago. Looks fine to me, but apparently not to the rest of you...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
lapply(Tables, function(x){
  rownames(x) <- colnames(x)
  x
})

# [[1]]
#               e      prod
# e    0.81014595 0.1898541
# prod 0.07925598 0.9207440
# 
# [[2]]
#           prod          e
# prod 0.9493263 0.05067374
# e    0.2401092 0.75989077
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option:

```
for (x in Tables) 
   data.table::setattr(x, "dimnames", list(colnames(x), colnames(x))) 


[[1]]
              e      prod
e    0.81014595 0.1898541
prod 0.07925598 0.9207440

[[2]]
          prod          e
prod 0.9493263 0.05067374
e    0.2401092 0.75989077
```

Comment: But why use `lapply` then? Just use a `for` loop if you want side effects.

Answer (score 4):

R already has everything you need :-)

```
Tables <- Map(`rownames<-`, Tables, lapply(Tables, colnames))
```

Comment: This deserves more votes IMHO because it shows the power of R's functional programming as well as the cool way you can turn an operator into a customized function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
lapply(seq_along(Tables), function(i) {
    rownames(Tables[[i]]) <<- colnames(Tables[[i]])
    return(invisible())
})
```

...which is ugly -- use a loop instead. Or, if you do want to use lapply, try:

```
Tables <- lapply(Tables, function(x) {
    rownames(x) <- colnames(x)
    return(x)
})
```

Someone posted this earlier but they seem to have deleted their answer.

Comment: The second one is the correct solution. The first one horribly violates principles of functional languages and goes against everything `lapply` is about, i.e., `lapply` is supposed to be a loop without side effects.

Comment: If you remove the first solution and leave the second, I'll upvote ;=)  Ooops, I see @Roland and I were thinking the same thing at the same time, but I'll leave my comment to help convince you there's some agreement about that first one's badness!

Comment: @Adrian thanks for your answer +1, and take into account Josh's comment to get another upvote.

Comment: I agree the first one is horrible and ugly and unreadable.  I was just trying to write something similar to the lapply(Tables, function(x) rownames(x) <- colnames(x)) in the original question.